# onHover doesn't show button even after zindex is set to maximum

Tags: css

I have the following problem in this webpage:

http://hashgurus.com/gallery3.aspx

On Hovering over the image, I should get a orange button visible, But I am not getting it. If you scroll down to the bottom (after some 50 images) and look at other images and on-hovering the image an orange button is visible.

I tried my best in increasing zindex but unsuccessful in getting the orange button.

What am I missing?

Comment: can you post your coding?

Comment: its pure javascript and css. you can look into view-source code.

Comment: The reason why he said post your code here is because your question will be irrelevant for future users that have the same problem as you; If you move the page or the page becomes a 404 .

Comment: The code is too big to be pasted upon here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

The opacity was set to 0. I changed it to 1 and the buttons appeared.

thanks...